# How to read string and get data from particular value using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have below string.

```
Message GID=1191539226 ID=1191539226-1
```

How do you retrieve the id value `1191539226-1` only using *vbscript split*

I used solution given by Ekkehard.Horner

Comment: So did you try to do that?

Comment: I tried out , Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the last part separated by "=". So:

```
>> s = "Message GID=1191539226 ID=1191539226-1"
>> a = Split(s, "=")
>> WScript.Echo a(Ubound(a))
>>
1191539226-1
>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split function:

```
Split(expression[,delimiter[,count[,compare]]])
```

Default delimiter is a space, so can most easily do this in 2 steps, the first to get `ID=1191539226-1`, and the second to split on `=`

For your example:

```
input = "Message GID=1191539226 ID=1191539226-1"
a = Split(input)
b = Split(a(2), "=")
result = b(1)
```